# Finding $E[Y|X]$ by finding $E[Y | X = x]$ and plugging in $X$ for $x$

Tags: expected-value

I read that if we're conditioning on a random variable ($X$ in our case), then to find $E[Y | X]$, we can simply first find $E[Y | X = x]$, then from this expression, we plug in $X$ everywhere we see $x$, and that gives us $E[Y | X]$. This seems very informal, so I'm hesitant to believe that this always works. Is this a sound approach to obtaining $E[Y | X]$?

Some examples include:

(1)
$$
E[Y | X = x] = 5x^2 \implies E[Y | X] = 5X^3
$$

(2) $Y$ is the number of heads in 10 coin tosses. $X$ is the number of heads in 3 coin tosses.

$E[Y | X = x] = x + 7p \implies E[Y | X] = X + 7p$

Comment: Your idea is correct.  Do you have a question?

Comment: I think this is the definition of the random variable $E[Y | X]$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg My question was just if this approach is actually sound in general.

Comment: Looks good.  Only caveat - be careful if R.V. has a continuous distribution.